# Sourcing and opening multiple files of same name, in specified folder, in Terminal? Is there a way?

Tags: terminal, command-line, file

Say I open terminal and change directory to folder 'folder', I type

```
cd folder.
```

Say there're multiple folders within this folder, i.e. data 1, data 2, data 3, etc., and within each of those is an image named 'image_a'. Is there a way to source all of the 'image_a' files, and open them via command line? Or write a script/run a function that does?

This part may be irrelevant, but they're NIfTI gzip (.nii.gz) files that I'll open via FSLview. The syntax to open a single image is

```
fslview </file>
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether `fslview` accepts several filenames at once and does the right thing based on that (the documentation/man page should have more details on this). If yes, you can run

```
cd folder
fslview data*/image_a
```

to have it open all files at once. If no, you can use

```
cd folder
for f in data*; do fslview "$f"/image_a; done
```

or

```
cd folder
for f in data*/image_a; do fslview "$f"; done
```

instead (the second option works better if there are `data X` directories which don't contain `image_a`).

PS: For a test run, replace `fslview` with `echo fslview` to see which command(s) would be executed.

Answer (score -3):

Try each of these

```
fslview image_a*

open image_a*
```